# Getting a manage page access token to upload events to a facebook page

Tags: facebook, events, upload, access-token, authorize

I'm writing code to allow uploading of events from a website to facebook, to do that I require a manage page access token, the procedure I`v found to obtain that is:

First Having added the domain to the app:

Then get a short term access token with:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[App ID]&redirect_uri=[full website uri]&scope=create_event&response_type=token

Then get a longer lasting access token from:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[App ID]&client_secret=[App Secret]&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[access token given above]

Then get a page specific token from:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[access token given above]

That returns a json encoded array with tokens for each page I manage which I gather lasts for 60 days.

However I don't manage the website I`m coding for, so don't wish to have to repeat this manual procedure every 2 months, can someone give an idea for an automated procedure or to confirm if such is not possible with facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are extending the user access token then the page token received will not have an expiry date. So then the user will only have to login *once* in the entire usage of the app.

> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thanks for that, however I notice every-time I make the request for a page token it returns a different one, does that not imply the user tokens are temporary?

I`ve read over the doc you linked to and its as clear as mud, I couldn`t find a definitive explanation.